# NPM link done at install time inside package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm in the process of creating 2 projects.
Project 1 will be like a library.
Project 2 will be an application which uses Project 1's library code.

So I wish to do a npm link from Project 1 to Project 2.  I can do this at the command line using the follow:

- cd ../project1 npm link
- cd ../project2 npm link project1_name

and it works fine.  But I don't wish to do that, I want when I install the package.json to not only set up the various dependencies to also set up the link.

So how would I do that in a npm script? 
I thought possibly - **"preinstall": "cd ../project1 npm link && cd ../project2 npm link project1_name",**

but that fails and I think it may have to do with what's the correct way to split up the various commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before I posted the question I tried a few more combinations and I got the answer -

You just need to place a **&&** between each command that you'd enter if you were doing it manually.

So the answer is -

**"preinstall": "cd ../project1 && npm link && cd ../project2 && npm link project1_name",**

I placed that into the scripts object in the package.json and now whenever the package is installed it will link to the library project